# Greengrass core auto discovery

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-iot, autodiscovery

I'm using greengrass v.1.5. Is there any API available for auto discovery of greengrass core (i.e API for activating "Automatically detect and override connection information" under greengrass group setting)?

Comment: Hi @K1.K - Did you get anywhere with this.  I'm asking a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308494/bulk-provisioning-of-greengrass-groups-cores-certificates