# Bulk provisioning of Greengrass Groups, Cores, Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm looking for some guidance with regards to the bulk provisioning of Greengrass 
Groups, Cores, Certificates.

In the pricing documentation for Greengrass https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/pricing/ it says:

> **Device B** - An AWS Greengrass Core device sits inactive on a warehouse
>   shelf in January, but is sold and powered on in February.....

In a similar scenario - thousands of Core devices sitting on a shelf in a shop waiting to be purchased - would one need to create Greengrass Group and Core in the AWS control panel for each device prior to purchase - or is it possible to do some sort of Just In Time provisioning of Greengrass Core devices as they come on-board?

Also, is there a Service Limit on AWS Greengrass Groups / Cores.  I've not found anything that mentions a limit, so I'm assuming not.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by service limit? Do you mean limitation of AWS Services on Greengrass side?

Comment: @Keivan - Yes, on the AWS Console side of things. Is there a limit to the number of Groups/Cores you can create? I ask as I'm assuming that I'd need a Group for every core device I have out in the field.  I don't think there is a limit as nothing is mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_greengrass

Comment: No, there is no limitation in number of Greengrass core and group. But there is a limitation in number of things in one Greengrass group which is 200.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just finished GrassFormation that might be of your interest. After installing it onto your account it allows you to provision Greengrass group and associated resources (cores, function definitions, resources, loggers, etc.) from a CloudFormation stack. Give it a try: https://github.com/Neosperience/GrassFormation

Answer (score 0):

You can do some sort of Just In Time provisioning. For that you should use one of the AWS IoT SDKs like Python (Boto) along with correct authentication and authorization, more information about python SDK for Greengrass can be found [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/greengrass.html?highlight=greengrass#Greengrass.Client.create_subscription_definition). You can find an example of thing provisioning using Python SDK [here](https://github.com/keivanK1/aws-create-thing-boto3).